# How to use Backbone to parse JSON?

Tags: javascript, json, backbone.js

I'm learning Backbone, with a little example. I have a JSON url, the result looks like this :

```
{
    help: "Help",
    success: true,
    result: {
        count: 13,
        results: [
            {
                name: "Name 1",
                description: "Desc 1",
                resources: [
                    {
                        img: "url.jpg"
                    }
                ]
            }, 
            {
                name: "Name 2",
                description: "Desc 2",
                resources: [
                    {
                        img: "url2.jpg"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Now I want to get all the results into a HTML div, so I used this:

```
$(function() {
    var Dataset = Backbone.Model.extend();

    var ProfileList = Backbone.Collection.extend({
        model: Dataset,
        url: 'profiles.json'    
    });   

    var ProfileView = Backbone.View.extend({
        el: "section#block-block-5",
        template: _.template($('#profileTemplate').html()),
        render: function(eventName) {
            _.each(this.model.models, function(profile){
                var profileTemplate = this.template(profile.toJSON());
                $(this.el).append(profileTemplate);
            }, this);

            return this;
        }
    });

    var profiles = new ProfileList();    
    var profilesView = new ProfileView({model: profiles});
    profiles.fetch({
        success: function(){
            profilesView.render();
        }
    });
});

<script id="profileTemplate" type="text/template">
    <div class="profile">
        <div class="info">
            <div class="name">
                <%= name %>
            </div>
            <div class="description">
                <%= description %>
            </div>
            <div class="image">
                <%= resources.url %>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</script>
```

The problem is that I don't know how to access the `results` group in JSON response.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: instead model pass a collection to view and in parse of collection return the desired data like response['result']['results'].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should use parse function to bind your model with `results` property of `result` element

```
var ProfileList = Backbone.Collection.extend({
        model: Dataset,
        url: 'profiles.json',
        parse: function (response) {
          return response.result.results;      
        }    
    });
```